# Is it possible to only show matching lines in tmux copy mode buffer?

Tags: buffer, tmux

I want to hide those irrelevant lines when I query a keyword in the buffer. Is there a simple way to achieve it? I can copy all the lines to a file and use vim to achieve this. But that would be very tedious

Answer (score 0):

No. Tmux copy mode is about moving around in the buffer, querying it and selecting it. Hiding non-matching lines would modify the buffer in copy mode, which is not something Tmux does.

Comment: Is there a way to open the buffer directly in vim?

Comment: @DerryGao, when you say the "tmux buffer", you could be referring to what's seen on the screen currently, or the entire scrollback buffer for a window.  It's already fairly fast to enter copy-mode, start a selection, extend it to the beginning of the buffer and select it:  C-<Prefix><Space>ggy  You can launch vim and paste. You could also look at scripting that sequence.